# Why are my collection items updating together even when I want them to have different colors?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, color, linked-data, collections

My collection items are changing colors together, even though I want them to have different colors?
I've equally placed the items into different collections, yet when I change material or color for one item, the item in the other collection changes.
I used Evee Engine to visualize the color change and all materials update together.
I tried clicking on unlink but when I do that, item I'm trying to unlink will disappear from my workspace.

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot explaining the problem ? For your information, collections are not exclusive, one object and its data can be a part of several collections, but it is still only one object.

Comment: Hello :). Just to add - if you change a material color on one object, all other objects with the same material will change too. You'll need a different material for each color.

Comment: I've found my way around it. It seems like once a mesh is copied, the copy automatically carries the properties of the parent mesh, hence; any material change to either the copied or the copy, effects changes the other. What I did was to delete the material properties of the mesh I wanted to have a different property and then add new properties to it.